# Are Dictionary Keys and Values enumerated in the same order?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have scenario where I have to send the Dictionary that was sent as an input as comma seperated strings to a stored procedure.

I am wondering whether if I do it like below will there be any possible case that it may send the incorrect value for a given key in the dictionary?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<int, string> test = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    test.Add(1, "1");
    test.Add(3, "3");
    test.Add(4, "4");
    test.Add(5, "5");
    test.Add(2, "2");
    JoinTest(test);
}

private static void JoinTest(Dictionary<int, string> test)
{
    var keys = string.Join(",", test.Keys);
    var values = string.Join(",", test.Values);
}
```

Comment: "as comma seperated strings to stored procedure" - if you're talking about a SQL Server stored procedure, why not pass the data across using a type *designed* for holding multiple values, such as XML or (better) a table-valued parameter? Why do string-mangling here and then force the database to do string-unmangling, just to get the data across?

Comment: I am using postgre sql

Answer (score 9):

Read the documentation. It clearly states:

> The order of the keys in the [Dictionary.KeyCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fcwy8h6(v=vs.110).aspx) is unspecified, but it is the same order as the associated values in the [Dictionary.ValueCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8bctb9c(v=vs.110).aspx) returned by the [Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

and

> The order of the values in the [Dictionary.ValueCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8bctb9c(v=vs.110).aspx) is unspecified, but it is the same order as the associated keys in the [Dictionary.KeyCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fcwy8h6(v=vs.110).aspx) returned by the [Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

So yes, keys and values match, but as commenters pointed out, you may have other problems here already.

Comment: Where "the same order as" is guaranteed only if no modifications to the Dictionary have occurred between the calls.

Comment: @user2864740: Well, I'd surely hope that if they modify the dictionary in between getting the keys and the values they are smart enough to notice that they are doing idiotic things. Same with modifying the dictionary concurrently from another thread.

Answer (score 1):

Joey's answer is correct, although the order is only guaranteed if no modifications has been made to the dictionary, as pointed out in the comments. If you want to make sure that the order is the same you can do like this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
var listOfKeyValuePairs = dictionary.ToList();
var keys = listOfKeyValuePairs.Select(kvp => kvp.Key);
var values = listOfKeyValuePairs.Select(kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The keys are also not null, nor duplicate (it will throw exception if that happens) so it won't send incorect values for a specific key (I think you are afraid that you will have same key for 2 or more items and the string.Join won't know which one to pick).
More information about Dictionary here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The question was more whether the enumeration order of `Keys` is the same as for `Values`, i.e. if you enumerate both separately, whether matching keys and values at the same index will match the mapping in the dictionary.

Comment: I wanted to post a comment at your response and not a new answer  @Joey. Your answer is the correct one.